# Display/Get Value in view from related Table by ID with Entity Framework in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working on Asp.Net Core application. I have 4 tables that are related...

```
public partial class AlarmInstall
{
    public int AlarmInstallId { get; set; }
    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public virtual House House { get; set; }
}

public partial class House
{
    public House()
    {
        AlarmInstall = new HashSet<AlarmInstall>();
    }

    public int HouseId { get; set; }
    public int StreetId { get; set; }
    public string DoorNr { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public virtual Street Street { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AlarmInstall> AlarmInstall { get; set; }
}

public partial class Street
{
    public Street()
    {
        House = new HashSet<House>();
    }

    public int StreetId { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<House> House { get; set; }
}

public partial class City
{
    public City()
    {
        House = new HashSet<House>();
    }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<House> House { get; set; }
}
```

Scafolfing all classes i am able to view with the AlarmInstalls/index.cshtml
But only the alarm model and DoorNr. I would like somehow to showThe StreetName and CityName Values associated to the HouseId

```
       <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Model)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.House)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.House.DoorNr)
        </td>
```

...

I want to view All the Alarmes i have instaled with the following info
AlarmeId - StreetName - DoorNr - CityName
I have look arround for any solution or examples but can´t seem to make it work.
Thanks for any help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Include` method to specify related data to be included in query results.You could also drill down through relationships to include multiple levels of related data using the `ThenInclude` method. Refer to the below code

```
var result= _context.AlarmInstall
                    .Include(a => a.House)
                         .ThenInclude(h=>h.Street)
                    .Include(a=>a.House)
                         ThenInclude(h=>h.City);
```

Reference : [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: @PedroNeff ,if you find my workaround works,could you mark my reply as the answer ? This will help others who have the same doubts . Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just Marked you reply as the answer! I am having a similar problem when i try to create a new alarm install. It is showing me the houses i have available by Id, but i need it to show the full address. the problem is that the house class only as the StreetId(from Street Class) and DoorNr. How can i manage to get it to show the full Address?